# Retrieve process- or thread-id of global keypress using SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c#, setwindowshookex

I've got a specific application which I can find using

```
Process.GetProcesses()
```

and filtering by ProcessName. 
I'd like to filter out all keypress-events of that process, unfortunately one can only pass a optional thread-id to [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) as last parameter.

That's why I thought about filtering the incoming events but I can't find a way to retrieve the information where it came from. Is there any solution to do it?

The callback-information are provided within [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) having another struct inside lparam: [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The keystroke goes to the window in the foreground.  So you need GetForegroundWindow() and GetWindowThreadProcessId().

Comment: @Hans Passant: This was helpful. Please post an answer so I can mark this as solved.
`Process process = Process.GetProcesses()
                .Where(x => x.ProcessName == "MyProcessName")
                .FirstOrDefault();
            //...
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            uint processID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (p2.Threads.OfType<ProcessThread>().Any(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(processID)))
                //success`

Comment: Just post the solution yourself and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

    Process process;

    public Form1() 
    {
        process = Process.GetProcesses()
            .Where(x => x.ProcessName == "MyProcessName")
            .FirstOrDefault();

        //init global keypress as needed
    }

    void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint processID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (p2.Threads.OfType<ProcessThread>().Any(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(processID)))
        {
            //keypress in MyProcessName
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```